# A twisted Cavalieri's Theorem Problem

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

**Question:- Find the volume of solid that lies between planes perpendicular to the axis of symmetry of cone and between $x=0$ to $x=12$. The cross section by planes perpendicular to the axis of symmetry are circular discs whose diameter run from the line $y=\frac{x}{2}$ to the line $y=x$.**

[image]

If the cross sections were perpendicular to the x-axis then it would be an fairly easy problem of **Cavalieri's Theorem**.But here cross sections are perpendicular to the axis of symmetry of truncated cone and that's makes it an tough problem.

Equation of axis of symmetry turns out to be $$y=\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{10}-1}{3}\bigg)x$$

I don't know how to integrate after that to find volume as cross sections are neither on x-axis nor y-axis.If we rotate the figure such that axis of symmetry coincides with the x-axis then that also doesn't help.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Diagram:  The stopping plane is perpendicular to the cone's axis at $x = 12$, so the cone's axis should extend to $x = 12$.  The circular base will extend to $x$s a little larger than $12$.

Comment: The diameters are line segments, perpendicular to the axis, with endpoints on $y = x$ and $y = x/2$.  For each $x \in [0,12]$, can you find the length of that segment meeting the cone axis at that $x$-coordinate?  (Perpendicular to $y = \frac{\sqrt{10}-1}{3}x$ means having slope $\frac{1-\sqrt{10}}{3}$.  And you know a point on this line segment -- it's the point on the cone axis with this $x$-coordinate.)

Comment: @Eric Towers That length turns out to be $\frac{\sqrt{20-2\sqrt{10}}}{4+2\sqrt{10}}x$

Comment: Well, now you have diameters.  The only detail to remember is that $\Delta (\text{distance along the cone's axis})$ is not the same as $\Delta x$ (by the ratio of the cosine of the angle between them).

Comment: @Eric Towers Thank you It will be $dxsec(\theta)$ and we will integrate from $x=0$ to $x=12$.

Comment: why do you say _If we rotate the figure such that axis of symmetry coincides with the x-axis then that also doesn't help_

Comment: @Math Lover In that case cross sections will be slanted to the x-axis not perpendicular.

Comment: No that's not correct. The shape of the cone does not change by change of coordinates and the cone itself is not a slanted cone.

Comment: I am talking about the cross-section which is perpendicular to the axis of symmetry. Once you do change of coordinates such that axis of symmetry $y=\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{10}-1}{3}\bigg)x$ aligns to x-axis, the cross-section is perp to the x-axis.

Comment: @Math Lover Thank you.I understand that but how can we find radius of cone?I have find out its height

Comment: The center of the base will be $\left((\sqrt{(\frac{\sqrt{10}-1}{3})^2 + 1}) \cdot 12, 0\right)$

Comment: @Math Lover How?.If possible can you please write the answer

Comment: @user1055 I can help in chat if you want

Comment: @Math Lover Yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133022/discussion-between-math-lover-and-user1055).